# How to find the solution of the equation $y'-Ay=-By^2$ (A,B>0)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the solution of the equation $y'-Ay=-By^2$ (A,B>0) ?

I found the integrating factor to be $e^{-Ax}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $z(t)=e^{-At}y(t)$. If you multiply both sides of the equation by the integrating factor $e^{-At}$ you get $$z'=-By^2e^{-At}=-Bz^2e^{At},$$which you should know how to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You have:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = Ay - By^2$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{Ay - By^2}$$
$$x = \int\frac{1}{Ay - By^2} ~ dy$$

You should be able to finish this now with partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: In other words, the DE is separable - didn't notice.